# YamlDotNet Serializer constructor throws exception

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I have to following code from the YamlDotNet docu https://dotnetfiddle.net/QlqGDV

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

public class ALogger {
    public function writeFile() {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_logFileCasesPath + @"\" + _logCaseName))
        {
            var ser = new Serializer();
            ser.Serialize(sw, _logCase);
        }
    }
}
```

But the new Serializer throws that exception and I don't know why. I didn't find any hint for that exception message.

```
Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.MissingMethodException" ist in InnoTest.exe aufgetreten.

Zusätzliche Informationen: Methode nicht gefunden: "Void YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer..ctor(YamlDotNet.Serialization.SerializationOptions, YamlDotNet.Serialization.INamingConvention, YamlDotNet.Serialization.YamlAttributeOverrides)".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another used framework had YamlDotNet in it already with version 3.8, but I used 3.9 so there was a conflict, but not found by compiler. Only at runtime there was the exception.

Cleanupedit:
I managed to get both libraries to the same version, than it worked. I then talked to the developers of the nuget packages to get them to use the nuget features for correct dependencie management.